How to find the general inverse of a matrix in python using SVD?
So I am trying to find the generalised inverse A+ of a matrix A using svd
this is my code for svd
A4 = np.array([[3, 1,2,3,4],
               [5,2,3,4,5],
               [7,4,5,6,7]])
print(A4)
U4, s4, V4 = np.linalg.svd(A4)
D4 = sp.linalg.diagsvd(s4, 3, 5)

print('UDVt =\n', U4@D4@V4 )

Which works fine and gives me the correct matrix
And this is the code that I am trying to use to get the generalised inverse
D4p = np.array([[D4[0,0]**-1,0,0],
                [0,D4[1,1]**-1,0],
                [0,0,D4[2,2]**-1],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,0]])
A4plus = np.transpose(V4) @ D4p @ np.transpose(U4) 
print(np.round(A4plus @ A4,2))
print(np.round(A4 @ A4plus,2))

I have tried changing the transposed matrixed.

So? It is a strange way to do it (with all that manual expansion). But it seems to be working, isn't it? You get exactly what np.linalg.pinv(A4) gives (I don't know whether it does the same or not. SVD is one way to compute Moore-Penrose inverse, not the only one). Or exactly what A4.T @ np.linalg.inv(A4@A4.T) gives. Which is another way. And A4@A4plus is, more or less, identity.

Isn't it what you were expecting?

@chrslg Yes this is what i was expecting for A4@A4plus but A4plus@A4 is not right. But I do agree with you that it gives the same as np.linalg.pinv(A4). SVD is just new to me so I was wondering why the results were so different and thought that I made an error in the code. But it seems the code is fine.

Don't expect A4plus @ A4 to be the identity matrix. That can generally not be reached, as you don't have sufficient row rank. And A4 @ A4plus is identity, as it should.

Assuming that the rows are not linear dependent (otherwise the S-matrix has elements of value zero and I cannot invert them), You can say
   U * S * Vt = A
=> A * (Vt.T * 1/S * U.T) = I

In code:
from numpy import array, round
from numpy.linalg import svd
from scipy.linalg import diagsvd

A = array([[3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           [7, 4, 5, 6, 7]])

U, S, Vt = svd(A)

S_inv = diagsvd(1/S, A.shape[1], A.shape[0])
A_inv = Vt.T @ S_inv @ U.T

print(round(A @ A_inv, 5))

This gives as a result the pseudo-inverse of A
[[ 1.  0. -0.]  [ 0.  1.  0.]  [-0. -0.  1.]]

Here is a relevant paragraph about this:
https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127/sp21/livebook/def_pseudo_inv.html

OK, so last comment make clear what the real question is: not about SVD per se, but about pseudo-inverse. Why, if A⁺ is the pseudo inverse, A⁺A is not identify (tho AA⁺ is)?
It doesn't matter how A⁺ is computed
Ap = np.linalg.pinv(A)
Ap = A.T@np.linalg.inv(A@A.T)
U,s,V = np.linalg.svd(A); Ap = (U@sp.linalg.diagsvd(1/s, 3, 5)@V).T

since the result is the same.
So answer to the real question is simple: pseudo-inverse is not inverse. We use it because inverse doesn't exist.
If A⁺A were also identity, then A⁺ would be the inverse of A.
∀u,v, Au=v ⇔ A⁺v=u, would mean that A is invertible and its inverse is A⁺.
Which can't be. Since it is a 3×5 matrix.
Think of it as information theory. If A⁺A were identity, that would be that if you have 5 numbers to store in a file, you could put them in a vector U=[u₁,u₂,u₃,u₄,u₅]. Compute V=AV. Which gives you only 3 numbers V=[v₁,v₂,v₃]. Store those 3 numbers in a file.
Then, when you want to retrieve the file, just compute U'=A⁺V, which is exactly U.
Perfect compression algorithm. That would works for all data U. ∀U, V=AU, then U'=A⁺V ⇒ U'=A⁺AU = IU = U.
Cannot be true. You can't represent all possible set of 5 number which 3 numbers. You can't fit an entire 5D space into a 3D space.
Compression algorithm do exist, of course. But they work for only a subset of possible data. They work because we know that actual data, that people are actually using, are only a very very small subset of all possible data.
Image compression works only because 99,99999999% of images looks like white noise to us, and only the remaining 0,00000001% looks like image of something.
Otherwise, that would be an impossibility.
Back to the linear world, that is what you have here. A "compression" of 5 numbers to 3, that works only for a 3D subset of your 5D space. That is if your data are a linear combination of the rows of A.
For example, for U=[1,2,3,4,5], AU = [51,69,103]. And A⁺AU = [1,2,3,4,5].
But that is because [1,2,3,4,5] happens to be 4*A₁-5A₂+2A₃ (the 3 rows of A).
So, if you happen to know that the U you are encountering do not lie on the entire 5D space, but only in a small 3D subspace of it, then, you can indeed expect to have that pseudo inverse working (that is, btw what SVD is. Finding actually relevant subspace).
But if U can be anything, not just a linear combination of rows of A, for example [1,0,4,8,2]. And AU is [43,59,89], and A⁺AU is then [1,2,3,4,5], not [1,0,4,8,2] (of course, I've chosen my example so that A@[1,2,3,4,5] = A@[1,0,4,8,2]. But point is, it cannot be unique. You cannot have a bijection between a 3D-space and a 5D-space).
Btw, [1,2,3,4,5] = A⁺@A@[1,0,4,8,2] is not any other u such as Au=A[1,0,4,8,2]; not just any other vector that shares Au result with [1,0,4,8,2].
It is the one that is a linear combination of rows of A. And that means something else. That means that A⁺A[1,0,4,8,2] is the linear combination of rows of A that is the closest (from square difference point of view) from [1,0,4,8,2].
The fact that A⁺A@[1,0,4,8,2] = [1,2,3,4,5] means that [1,2,3,4,5] is the linear combination of rows of A that minimize ||AU-[1,0,4,8,2]||
Which is yet another way to see pseudo inverse.
If A was a rank 5 matrix. Then linear combinations of rows of A would be the whole 5D-space. In other words, any vector X would be a linear combination of rows of A. So, you would expect A⁺AX to be X. Because X is a linear combination of rows of A, and among those, which one can be closer to X than X itself?
So A⁺AX=X ∀X. So A⁺A=Id. So A⁺ is not just a pseudo-inverse. It is the inverse.
But since A is not rank 5, then not all vectors X are linear combination of rows of A. And then, if you want to find a linear combination of rows of A that resemble X, you need to solve least square problem, and find Y, such as Y is a linear combination of rows of A and ||X-Y|| is minimum.
It cannot be 0 each time. But you can get as close as possible. By saying Y=A⁺AX
Or, using rows combinations: A⁺ᵀ X are the coefficients of the rows of A that is the closest to X. For example, for X=[1,0,4,8,2] Ap.T@X = [4,-5,2], meaning that you cannot get αA₁+βA₂+γA₃ closer to X than with α=4, β=-5 γ=2. And then αA₁+βA₂+γA₃ = A⁺AX =[1,2,3,4,5].
But of course, if it were [1,0,4,8,2] instead of [1,2,3,4,5], that would mean that any vector X is a linear combination of rows of A. And that can't be, right? You can't have any 5D vector be a linear combination of 3 vectors.
tl;dr
A⁺A is not identity because otherwise it would be an inverse, not a pseudo-inverse.
AA⁺ is identity, because AA⁺Y (Y being 3D vector) is the closest to Y linear combination of columns of A. If A is rank 3, there is one linear combination of columns of A that is exactly Y for all Y. Hence AA⁺=Id
A⁺A is not identity, because A⁺AX (X being 5D vector) is the closest to X linear combination of rows of A. And you cannot have an exact combination of the 3 rows of A that is X, for all X.
